# sales_order_place_before Observer Event not working in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, event-observer

I have created an event `sales_order_place_before`. But it's not working.

You can see my code here :

*app/code/Test/Inquiry/etc/frontend/events.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
   <event name="sales_order_place_before">
      <observer name="Test_Inquiry_sales_order_place_before"  
           instance="Test\Inquiry\Observer\OrderPlacebefore"/>
   </event>
</config>
```

Here is observer code:

*app/code/Test/Inquiry/Observer/OrderPlacebefore.php*

```
namespace Test\Inquiry\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class OrderPlacebefore implements ObserverInterface
{
 protected $_objectManager;

  public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager
  ) {
      $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
  }

  public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
  {
       echo  "Hello Testing ";die();
  }
}
```

Can you please help me to resolve the issue ?

Comment: Make sure this module works. And then, try clear your Magento Cache.

Comment: Yes, I am dem sure this module is work and also i have cleared cache and indexing.but still not working.

Comment: current issue is observer not working if i put events,xml outside frontend folder than observer is working but redirecting automatically on cart page and if i put events.xml in frontend folder than it's not working.

Comment: How about your current issue?

Answer (score 5):

@Kartik,

You should put you events.xml in webapi_rest folder. Path will be `etc/webapi_rest/events.xml`. It will work.

Actually It was magento internal issue. They have resolved it. [Look Here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/1581)

Comment: It is working fine

Comment: Thanks, that was indeed working! But how to figure something like this out?? I will never use observers again, from now on I will only use plugins...

Answer (score 4):

Put your `events.xml` file outside the `frontend` folder.

**app/code/Test/Inquiry/etc/events.xml**

If we put the `events.xml` under `etc/frontend`. It may not work.
I'm not sure that it may be a bug.

Comment: I have already put in etc/frontend.

Comment: Put your `event.xml` file outside the `frontend` folder.

Comment: Now i got the message in observer but it's redirect the page automatically  on cart page. can you please suggest what the issue. This issue occuring after put my event.xml file outside in frontend folder. can you please suggest me what can i do ?

Comment: This is normal because you tried to die the checkout process. I think your observer can work now!

Comment: If your observer can work, so, your current issue solved, please accept the answer.

Comment: Actually this issue occurred after change the place of events.xml and also i can't get all data in observer so can you please suggest me from where the issue is being generated ?

Comment: In your observer,  we can get the order object? `$observer->getOrder()`

Comment: The issue is because of your die() statement...