# Magento 2 - event is not getting triggered - observer not working

Tags: magento2, event-observer

This is my code. The event is not getting triggerd after I place a new order.

**app/code/Company/RalSurcharge/etc/frontend/events.xml** (i also tried *app/code/Company/RalSurcharge/etc/events.xml*)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_order_place_before">
        <observer name="company_ralsurcharge_sales_order_place_before" instance="Company\RalSurcharge\Observer\RalSurcharge2" />
    </event>
</config>
```

**app/code/Company/RalSurcharge/Observer/RalSurcharge2.php**

```
<?php
namespace Company\RalSurcharge\Observer;

use \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;

class RalSurcharge2 implements ObserverInterface
{   
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/observer.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);
        $logger->info("Hello from sales_order_place_before observer");
    }



}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. The problem is the number in the filename. I changed it from RalSurcharge2 to RalSurchargeTwo, now it works...

If it still not works, then it can be because the file `events.xml` is in the wrong folder. I wonder why it ever worked for me, normally it has to be in `MODULE/etc/webapi_rest`

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/189439/66769

Answer (score 3):

Avoid digits or any special symbols in file names or Class names.

For the fast and easy creation of basic files, you can use https://mage2gen.com/ tool. It'll generate all needed files automatically for you so that you do not have to worry about the files and it's structure.